# Configure app layout when adjusting screen size - dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I've tried to set the max height/width on `dbc` components within an app but when adjusting the screen size, the layout changes. Is there a way to make the layout more flexible to ensure the same configuration when adjusting the screen size.

With below, output 1 is what is expected. When adjusting the screen size smaller (output 2), the layout changes. Is it possible to maintain the same layout as output 1?

Is it also possible to make the cards the exact same size?

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.COSMO, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

navbar = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        html.H3('NavBar', style = {'color':'white', 'fontSize': 30, 'textAlign':'center'}),

    ], className = "four columns vstack gap-2 h-75",
    style = {'padding':'2rem'}
    )
])

banner = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            html.H1('xxxx'),
            html.H5('xxxx')
        ], 
    ),
    className='text-center bg-secondary text-light border border-3 align-self-center'
)

card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Header", className="lead"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.P("x", className="card-text"),
            ], 
        ), 
    ], className = "border border-3 text-center m-4 mw-50",
style={'height':'75%', "verticalAlign": "bottom" }
)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row(banner),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(html.Div(navbar), className = 'bg-secondary border border-3 h-50'),
            ]),
        ], 
        ),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(card),
                dbc.Col(card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                html.Button('Button',
                style={'font-size': '14px', 'width': '200px', 'height': '40px', 'display': 'inline-block', 
                       'margin-top': '0px', 'margin-left': '525px', 
                       'horizontalAlign':'right', 'verticallAlign':'top'
                      }
                ),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(), style={
                        "height": "50%",
                        "padding-top": "10px",
                        "padding-bottom": "10px",
                    }),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                html.Button('Button',
                style={'font-size': '14px', 'width': '200px', 'height': '40px', 'display': 'inline-block', 
                       'margin-top': '20px', 'margin-left': '525px', 
                       'horizontalAlign':'right', 'verticallAlign':'top'
                      }
                ),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(), style = {
                    'height': '50%',
                    "padding-top": "10px",
                    "padding-bottom": "10px",
                    }),
            ]),
        ], width = 4
        ),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(card),
                dbc.Col(card),
                dbc.Col(card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                html.Button('Button',
                style={'font-size': '14px', 'width': '200px', 'height': '40px', 'display': 'inline-block', 
                       'margin-top': '0px', 'margin-left': '700px', 
                       'horizontalAlign':'right', 'verticallAlign':'top'
                      }
                ),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(html.Div(dcc.Graph()), style = {
                    'height': '100%',
                    "padding-top": "10px",
                }
                ),
            ], 
            ),
        ], width = 5
        ),
    ])
], fluid=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8050)
```

Output 1:

[image]

Output 2 (smaller):

[image]

Output 3:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `xs, md, lg` to arrange your `Col`. Please refer below code:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.COSMO, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

navbar = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        html.H3('NavBar', style = {'color':'white', 'fontSize': 30, 'textAlign':'center'}),

    ], className = "four columns vstack gap-2 h-75",
    style = {'padding':'2rem'}
    )
])

banner = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            html.H1('xxxx'),
            html.H5('xxxx')
        ], 
    ),
    className='text-center bg-secondary text-light border border-3 align-self-center'
)

card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Header", className="lead"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.P("x", className="card-text"),
            ], 
        ), 
    ], className = "border border-3 text-center m-4 mw-50",
style={'height':'75%', "verticalAlign": "bottom" }
)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row(banner),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(html.Div(navbar), className = 'bg-secondary border border-3 h-50'),
            ]),
        ],xs = 2, sm=2, md=2, lg=2 
        ),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
            ], justify="center"),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    dbc.Button('Button',size='sm', color='dark')
                ], width={'size':6}, style={'text-align':'right'}),
                dbc.Col([
                    dbc.Button('Button',size='sm', color='dark')
                ], width={'size':6}, style={'text-align':'right'})
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    dcc.Graph()
                ], width={'size':6}),
                dbc.Col([
                    dcc.Graph()
                ], width={'size':6}),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    dbc.Button('Button',size='sm', color='dark')
                ], width={'size':6}, style={'text-align':'right'}),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    dcc.Graph()
                ], width={'size':6}),
            ])
        ],xs = 10, sm=10, md=10, lg=10)
    ])
], fluid=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port = 8056)
```

- Full screen:
  [image]
- Resize:
  [image]

Hope this help.

Updated answer:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.COSMO, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

navbar = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        html.H3('NavBar', style = {'color':'white', 'fontSize': 30, 'textAlign':'center'}),

    ], className = "four columns vstack gap-2 h-75",
    style = {'padding':'2rem'}
    )
])

banner = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            html.H1('xxxx'),
            html.H5('xxxx')
        ], 
    ),
    className='text-center bg-secondary text-light border border-3 align-self-center'
)

card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Header", className="lead"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.P("x", className="card-text"),
            ], 
        ), 
    ], className = "border border-3 text-center m-4 mw-50",
style={'height':'75%', "verticalAlign": "bottom" }
)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row(banner),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(html.Div(navbar), className = 'bg-secondary border border-3 h-50'),
            ]),
        ],xs = 2, sm=2, md=2, lg=2 
        ),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
                dbc.Col(card, width={'size':2}),
            ], justify="center"),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    dbc.Button('Button',size='sm', color='dark')
                ], width={'size':6}, style={'text-align':'right'}),
                dbc.Col([
                    dbc.Button('Button',size='sm', color='dark')
                ], width={'size':6}, style={'text-align':'right'})
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                dbc.Card([
                    dbc.CardBody([
                        dbc.Row([
                            dcc.Graph(style={'height':400}),
                        ]),
                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([
                            dbc.Button('Button',size='sm', color='dark'),
                            ], width={'size':12}, style={'text-align':'right'}),  
                        ]),
                        dbc.Row([                        
                            dcc.Graph(style={'height':400})
                            ]),
                        ]),
                    ]),
                ],xs = 6, sm=6, md=6, lg=6),
                dbc.Col([
                    dbc.Card([
                    dbc.CardBody([
                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([
                                dcc.Graph(style={'height':835})
                            ], width={'size':12}),
                        ])
                    ])
                    ])
                ],xs = 6, sm=6, md=6, lg=6)
            ])
        ],xs = 10, sm=10, md=10, lg=10)
    ])
], fluid=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port = 8056)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Is it possible to widen the `nav-bar` and lengthen the right-side figure so it's the same length as the two left-hand figures?

Comment: DO you have expected Output?

Comment: I'll attach one. Nav-bar is easy enough. Just change 10-2 to 9-3. But I'm hoping the right side figure is the same length as the two left-hand side figures

Comment: @Chopin: I updated answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks but I'm missing the button above the bottom left hand figure

Comment: @Chopin: I uptead answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hoa tran. Can I add in a space between the two left-hand side figures?

Comment: @Chopin: I think you should separate them by using dbc.Card